# How to identify an unknown exit code?

Tags: xcode, macos, exit

I have the problem that a Mac application I wrote often suddenly exits with a for me unknown exit code 33 and without any further indication of what went wrong. I already searched the whole source code for the number 33, but I couldn't find anything (I was hoping for a line of code like `exit(33)`).

Can you give me any hint how I could track down this problem? Is there a way for example to set a breakpoint into the exit-function or something like that?

Comment: You'll need to add more logging to your app to see what it was doing at the time `exit()` was called.

Comment: ... or you could run it inside `dtrace`.

Comment: Is it a standard error code, maybe? By googling I got -33 for directory full, or 33 for invalid argument to floating point function. But running it in xcode under the debugger should give you a more verbose message.

Comment: Ok, I've added log-code to various parts of my application (function-start/function-end etc.). The app is running already for hours without this exit-33 and the log-file is already about 100MB. ;) Let's see, if this approach will lead to any new information.

Answer (score 0):

There are no predefined meanings for a processes exit code. The C standard defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` without numeric values. On Unix-like systems they are defined to 0 and 1. Unix limits those exit to an unsigned 8-bit integer, so they range from 0 to 255, but the meaning for each exit code (except 0 for success) is up to the developer.

FreeBSD defines a couple of values as documented on the [sysexits(3) manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&sektion=3). But the number 33 is not among them.

Your best way to debug this problem would be to set a breakpoint to the various `exit` functions (`exit`, `_exit`) and see when and where they get called.

Comment: I already checked my whole source code for exit-calls and none of them could create the code 33. It must be created by a system-function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was an exit-call `exit(12321)` in my code, which gets reported in the console as 33. It seems the status-parameter of `exit(int)` can not be an arbitrary int-value.

Comment: (12321 & 0x7f) == 33. In what way, or which part of, the argument of exit() is communicated to the environment is highly system-dependent. Many shells only keep the lower 7 bits, as in your case.